# Get "group by" parameter column name/ alias from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `podcast`. Each podcast has category and subcategory associated to it in the form of ids.

[image]

This category_id and subcategory_id have their name values in their respective tables -

[image]
[image]

Now, I want to get the count of podcasts under each category, subcategory combination -

```
SELECT podcast_category_id, podcast_subcategory_id, count(*)
FROM podcasts
where podcast_owner = 14 AND podcast_upload_time_stamp >= timestamp '2020-10-22 00:00:00'
GROUP BY podcast_category_id, podcast_subcategory_id
```

Output -

[image]

The output shows `podcast_category_id` and `podcast_subcategory_id` columns as expected. However, I want to replace `podcast_category_id` with `category_name` and `podcast_subcategory_id` with `sub_category_name`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join to those tables.

```
    SELECT c.category_name, sc.sub_category_name, count(p.*)
    FROM podcasts p
    join categories c
      on c.category_id = p.podcast_category_id
    join sub_categories sc
      on sc.sub_category_id = p.podcast_subcategory_id
    where p.podcast_owner = 14 
      AND p.podcast_upload_time_stamp >= timestamp '2020-10-22 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY 1,2
```